# Should I just ban everyone who has no language setting?

Tags: language, referrer

I am constantly seeing in my logs the same type of visitor:
They have no language setting, i.e.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] == ''
```

so it's empty, and their referrer is some scam server in Russia or Ukraine. I get many of these every day. I've been banning them selectively based on their referrer but it seems I am getting similar non-browser based visitors from China as well who have no referrer. So should I just ban these people or bots?

Examples of referrers:

```
http://www.odeialo.ru/
http://www.moregirls.org/
http://segway911.ru/
```

Comment: You can block on referrers but be-careful proceeding with blocking based on language since some people like to stay anonymous and use various chrome/firefox extensions that block data collecting and I believe that some even block the language.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a reason to believe such requests are harming your site or affecting the experience of legitimate users, I suggest you avoid any broad rule to block visitors. They may occur for legitimate people which would be counter-productive.

Now, if something bad is happening, such as longer response time for visitors, excessive bandwidth usage, etc, then keep an eye on the logs to find out which rule to base your ban on. If it is really that there is no accept-language, so be it but I'd try more specific things first.